# How do I open a file with a text editor in Go?

Tags: file, go

I'm working on an CLI tool that lets you create files easily and opens it if a certain flag is true. This is the only way of opening a file in a text editor that I saw:

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command(file)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Start failed: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Waiting for command to finish.\n")
    err = cmd.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("Command finished with error: %v\n", err)
```

...which I don't really understand by the way, and got the following error:

```
Start failed: fork/exec H:/code/txt_projects/hello6.txt: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.Waiting for command to finish.
Command finished with error: exec: not started
```

How do I fix this? How can I open the file with, for example, Notepad?

Comment: You call `exec.Command` on a file path string directly, you should call it on a string whose content is a executable `shell` or `cmd` (Win32) command instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `exec.Command` on a string whose content is a executable command path, with some arguments for this command as other parameters, like:

```golang
    // shortcut for command in ENV PATH
    //exepath := "notepad"
    exepath := "C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"
    file := "H:\\code\\txt_projects\\hello6.txt"
    cmd := exec.Command(exepath, file)
```

Refer to [document](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command).